# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException - Package

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, package

I'm going through the OCA Java SE 7 study guide and am going through packages. However, I'm inputting the same code in Eclipse, found in the book but I'm getting this error. 
The error is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.ocaj.exam.tutorial.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:12)

Here is my code...

```
package com.ocaj.exam.tutorial;     //Package statement

//Imports class ArrayList from the java.util package
import java.util.ArrayList;
//Imports all classes from the java.io package
import java.io.*;

public class MainClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Creates console from java.io package
    Console console = System.console();
    String planet = console.readLine("\nEnter your favourite planet: ");
        //Creates list for planets
    ArrayList planetList = new ArrayList();
    planetList.add(planet);             //Adds users input into the list
    planetList.add("Gliese 581 c");     //Adds a string to the list
    System.out.println("\nTwo cool planets: " + planetList);
}
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`System.console` can return `null` depending on the environment in which the JVM is operating.

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html)

> If no console device is available then an invocation of that method will return null.

Eclipse is one of these environments where the `System.console` returns `null` since it typically uses `javaw` which doesnt have an associated console window.

Use [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) instead which has no such limitation.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String planet = scanner.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.console()` will return null if the program you're running doesn't have a console associated. Try running your program in a console (a "command prompt").

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not running it directly from a system console if you are using eclipse.

To make it work replace the following code:

```
String planet = console.readLine("\nEnter your favourite planet: ");
```

By:

```
System.out.print("\nEnter your favourite planet: ");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String planet = scanner.nextLine();
scanner.close();
```